# UITextfield cursor moves

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I am trying to change the UITextField font size dynamically when text changes.
But when i do that my textfield cursor moves to up.
So if anybody knows the solution please help.

[image]

Please check the image for reference.
Thanks.

```
-(void)textChanged:(id)sender{

    UITextField *textFild = (UITextField*)sender;
    if ([textFild.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        [textFild setFont:FONT_30];
    }
    else{
        [textFild setFont:FONT_15];
    }
    textFild.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
}
```

Please check the code..

Answer (score 1):

Add this line after setting font size dynamically. This will work for you.

```
txtFieldPassword.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
```

Instead of `txtFieldPassword` write `IBOutlet` name of your respective `textfield`.

Comment: Can you please add some code here regarding setting font to textfield.

Answer (score 0):

This is an expected behaviour. Set the text of the textfield along with the font.So the cursor will be reset to normal position.

```
-(void)textChanged:(id)sender {
    UITextField *textFild = (UITextField*)sender;
    NSString *tmpString = textFild.text; 
    if ([textFild.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        textFild.text=tmpString;
        [textFild setFont:FONT_30];
    } else {
         textFild.text=tempString;
        [textFild setFont:FONT_15];
    }
    textFild.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
}
```